# Object pool design pattern in golang

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, go

I am studying design patterns in go. I need a review of this implementation. I started this exercise from wikipedia description of the pattern and implementing step by step all the sentences.

I decided to use two objects: the pool and the object managed by the pool.

```
type PoolObject struct {
    id int
}

type Pool struct {
    idle   *list.List
    active *list.List
}
```

When pool is initialized two empty lists were created.

```
func InitPool() Pool {
    pool := &Pool{
        list.New(),
        list.New(),
    }
    return *pool
}
```

Any time an object is requested, it's returned from the idle list or created from scratch.

```
func (p *Pool) Loan() PoolObject {
    if p.idle.Len() > 0 {
        for e, i := p.idle.Front(), 0; e != nil; e, i = e.Next(), i+1 {
            if i == 0 {
                object := e.Value.(PoolObject)
                return object
            }
        }
    }

    object := PoolObject{p.NumberOfObjectsInPool() + 1}
    p.active.PushBack(object)
    return object
}
```

Any time an object is returned, it's removed from the active list and pushed in the idle list.

```
func (p *Pool) Receive(object PoolObject) {
    p.idle.PushBack(object)
    for e, i := p.active.Front(), 0; e != nil; e, i = e.Next(), i+1 {
        if object == e.Value.(PoolObject) {
            p.active.Remove(e)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In real code you'd use a [`sync.Pool`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Pool) (typically with tiny type safe wrappers around `Pool.Get` and `Pool.Put` for each specific pool type you use).

Comment: Go's `container` packages are rarely used in real code. Only use a `list.List` if you really need the properties of a doubly linked list, in the vast vast majority of cases a simple slice is much better and faster. In this case, you'd append items to an idle slice and pull off the tail end of it (i.e. use a slice as a LIFO queue; btw, a LIFO is preferable here vs FIFO both because it's easier to efficiently do the former with a slice and because recent objects are more likely to be in CPU/memory caches and should preferentially be reused first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop doesn't loop:

> ```
> for e, i := p.idle.Front(), 0; e != nil; e, i = e.Next(), i+1 {
>     if i == 0 {
>         object := e.Value.(PoolObject)
>         return object
>     }
> }
> ```

On the first iteration, *if there is a first iteration*,
it will return the first value from the pool.
This should be written as a condition:

```
if e := p.idle.Front(); e != nil {
    return e.Value.(PoolObject)
}
```

---

The variable `i` is not used in this loop:

> ```
> for e, i := p.active.Front(), 0; e != nil; e, i = e.Next(), i+1 {
>     if object == e.Value.(PoolObject) {
>         p.active.Remove(e)
>         return
>     }
> }
> ```

It has no reason to be there, so it should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't seem to have a policy for a maximum pool side. Is that by mistake or by design? What should happen if someone requests an object too many?
2. Your choice of method names is slightly off. When I talk to an object pool, I don't want to Loan it an object, nor do I want to Receive an object. I want to "borrow," "obtain," "take" or "get" an object from the pool, and I want to "return" or "release" or "put" an object back into the pool.

   I'd suggest:

   ```
   obj = pool.Borrow()
   // ...
   pool.Return(obj)
   ```
3. Finally, why does your object have an `id`? It seems unused. I'd suggest just using [`interface{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148812/go-whats-the-meaning-of-interface) as your object type.

Comment: 1. good point. I'll improve the implementation.
2. Borrow is better also for me. Thank you.
3. Just for test purpose. Maybe is better to just check if objects are equals, instead of check their id.